# Create Table variable datatype that would allow to save integer/floats [SQL]

Tags: sql, types, numbers, create-table

as the title states, when creating a table, when definining an variable + datatype like:

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable{
ID INTEGER,
NAME VARCHAR(200),
Integerandfloat 
}
```

**Question:** You can define a variable as integer or as float etc. however, is there a datatype that can hold both values, integer as well as a float number ?

Comment: A column in SQL is of one datatype, only NoSQL could accommodate more datatypes in the same column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases support variant data types that can have an arbitrary type.  For instance, SQL Server has [`sql_variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Most databases also allow you to create your own data type (using `create type`).  However, the power of that functionality depends on the database.

For the choice between a float and an integer, there isn't much choice.  An 8-byte floating point representation covers all 4-byte integers, so you can just use a float.  However, `float` is generally not very useful in relational databases.  Fixed-point representations (`numeric`/`decimal`) are more common and might also do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just store it using float.

Think in this way: you have two variables, one integer type (let's call it `i`) and another float type (let's call it `f`).
If you do:

```
i = 0.55
RESULT -> i = 0
```

But if you have:

```
f = 0.55
RESULT -> f = 0.55
```

In this way you can store in f also integer value:

```
f = 1
RESULT -> f = 1
```